# Code doesn't behave like conditions are being met when they are? [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have the following function:

```
def ask_question():
    """Asking a question which requires a yes or no response"""
    response=input()
    while response.lower()!="yes" or response.lower()!="no":
        print("Invalid response! Answer must be 'Yes' or 'No'.")
        response=input()
    return response
```

Yet when I execute the function ask_question() and type "yes" or "no", it comes up with the response "Invalid response! Answer must be 'Yes' or 'No'."

I can't figure out for the life of me why and i've been staring at it for a while now. Can someone help me out?

Comment: The `or` should be an `and`. The response will always be different from at least one of the strings. E.g. if it's `"yes"` then `response.lower()!="no"` will be true, and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `and` in your loop. But why?

According to [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), your condition

```
response.lower()!="yes" or response.lower()!="no":
```

Is equivalent to: `(not A) or (not B)` which is the same as `not (A and B)` - which is not what you want (i.e. `not (Yes and No)` does not give you what you want).

Therefore changing your query to use the `and` would change to this:

```
response.lower()!="yes" and response.lower()!="no":
```

which is equivalent to `(not A) and (not B)` which is the same as `not (A or B)` which is what you want. In other words:

```
if input is "not (Yes or No)", print invalid reponse msg
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks prints the message *if the input in lower case is **not** `"yes"`, **or** the input in lower case is **not** `"no"`*, which is `True` pretty much for all possible inputs the user can give. Of course you could do `if response.lower() != "yes" and response.lower() != "no":` but it would not be very pythonic.

Instead you'd probably want to do the following with the `in` operator:

```
def ask_question():
    """Asking a question which requires a yes or no response"""

    while True:
        response = input("Please answer 'yes' or 'no'> ").lower()
        if response not in ('yes', 'no'):
            print("Invalid response! Answer must be 'yes' or 'no'.")
        else:
            return response
```

This code also ensures that the the user has answered correctly the second time when prompted.